# Want to show minecraft player stats on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web, plugins, minecraft, wordpress-shortcode

I want to display Minecraft server stats and player information on my WordPress website like

https://www.veltpvp.com

https://www.lunar.gg/

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that Tebex has an automated feature like that, all those sites seem to use Tebex

May be wrong though